# How to append data to a compressed file?

Tags: swift, file, filesystems, zip, compression

I am getting a lot of data from websocket screem and I want to store them on disk. The amount of data received is ~300 MB per hour and I want to store this data long term (months, years).

In .NET there is a way how to read/write from/to zipped files using compressed streams. Is there a way to write directly to compressed file in Swift?

This is Mac OS (OSX) question.

---

**Edit:**

[Stream compression here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/data_compression#topics) might be a solution but I am not used to work with unsafe pointers and don't even know whether it can be used to write to compressed file... I am stacked on this for few hours now. Code sample or directions how to approach it would help. Cocoapods wrapper for stream compression would be even better.

Comment: GitHub is usually your friend here. Have never used this but appends to zipped files; https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive.

Comment: @PriceRingo Nice catch, thank you. However, the resulting .zip filles seems to corrupted or incompatible, at least I cannot unzip them normally.

Comment: Since you mention months/years, i'd assume you'll have multiple files to keep it practical. So, why not just write say hourly uncompressed files and have some periodic task to pack up the old ones (a bit like what logrotate does).

Answer (score 1):

[gzlog](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) does what you're looking for. It is written in C and uses the zlib library. zlib is available on macOS, and you can link to C code from Swift.